# Why Vue v-model expand differently in component and native element

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

In the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html), it is said that:

```js
<input v-model="searchText" />
// becomes
<input
  :value="searchText"
  @input="searchText = $event.target.value"
/>
```

but

```js
<CustomInput v-model="searchText" />
// becomes
<CustomInput
  :model-value="searchText"
  @update:model-value="newValue => searchText = newValue"
/>
```

Note the `:model-value`/`modelValue` props. Why doesn't custom input props become `:value`, just like the native one? Like this:

```
<CustomInput v-model="searchText" />
// becomes
<CustomInput
  :value="searchText"
  @input="newValue => searchText = newValue"
/>
```

Comment: v-model is two way and v-value is one way. if you use v-model in text input if you change the value in input it will get updated in that variable. but if v-value then i will take it as a value and if you change the value in input, the variable will not get updated.

Comment: @Neha I understand the 2-way binding part. But I'm asking for some other detail. Please see the updated question. I changed `:model` to `:value`.

Comment: This is the way it works in Vue 3 (which the question doesn't take into account) and this is documented. It was value instead of modelValue in 2. Probably was changed because it caused name collisions, "value" prop name is too common. When a third-party comp accepts modelValue prop, you already know it follows v-model convention, no need to check the way it's implemented

Answer (score 1):

1. If you use `@input` on custom components it would be impossible to bind this event to the real `<input>` used in a component.
2. Having different event and prop names for native and custom components is a good idea to avoid any possible conflicts.
3. `v-model` could handle multiple props: `v-model.prop2` - some other prop could be bound too.
4. `@input="newValue => searchText = newValue"` - you can't do that since `newValue` is an event, not a new value.
5. using `v-model` on native inputs is a good abstraction to avoid bothering about which exact native event we need for value changes.
6. If you are a novice I wouldn't question decisions made by a framework's creators being you yet.